# Are these functions? console.log(), substring(), confirm(), toUpperCase(), etc

Tags: javascript

How are the following javascript functions implemented?

- `console.log()`
- `substring()`
- `confirm()`
- `toUpperCase()`

What goes on behind the scenes? Are these native Javascript functions? 
When a token followed by parentheses `()` containing arguments is encountered by the interpreter, is it executing a built-in function behind the scenes?

The `substring(a,b)` method takes arguments. What about `console.log()` or `toUpperCase()` for example?

Is the text you enter between the parentheses technically an argument for a function?

I'm writing about these commands in a report as part of my studies and I need to know how to describe them. Would I be correct in calling them functions?

Comment: try `typeof` , you will know what they are

Comment: `console` and `confirm` are methods from the `window` object. `substring` is a method from the `String` object. Look at what's _calling_ these methods to find out who's defining them. Also then `()` you're referring to executes a function, so if you're able to do `something()` without an error, it's probably a function.

Comment: to clarify @A.J's excellent point, use `typeof console.log` for example, not `typeof console.log()`

Comment: @NickZuber - `probably`? I'm racking my little grey cells trying to think where it wouldn't be a function :p

Comment: @JaromandaX constructors are probably a grey area

Comment: d'oh, of course

Comment: @AnthonySottile constructors are still themselves functions afaik, even if the invocation is a bit funny and return value discarded effectively. perhaps `get` / `set` would be more on the ambiguous side?

Comment: You can make functions that are `typeof` `"function"` but not `instanceof` `Function` and objects that are `typeof` `"object"` but still `instanceof` `Function`.